# Tips before publishing project - and how do I push updates?

Tags: c#, updates, clickonce, publish

As I said in the title: Do any of you have **tips/steps** that I should go over before **publishing** my project, and how do I **push an update?**

I've been developing on a C# project for about 2.5 years. Started on it when I was 13, and now I'm 15. The project is for my local schools in town. It's a "digital math test" that both children and adults can use.

My question is: Do any of you have any **tips** before publishing? Things in code that I can **optimize**, and when I publish, how do I push **updates**? I've used **Squirrel** before but I had problems with it. I've considered **ClickOnce**, because pushing an update is as simple as **pushing a button**. I don't really understand how to set up ClickOnce though.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't really understand how to set up ClickOnce though.

It all depends on how you want to deploy your application... Could you add more information on how you want to deploy it?

If you work locally, it's very simple, when you publish an update, the new version is pushed to the publish folder and when you launch your application it detects it and installs it.

Comment: I want to deploy my application so that I get an .msi or .exe file I can distribute. The updates must be pushed **"over the internet"**, so that all users get the update no matter where they are.

Comment: ClickOnce will give you a .exe file that will install your application. You can parameter it to check for updates everytime you launch the application.